# set a color value in the attributes file

Tags: android, colors, attributes

I need a hit on how to set a color I have defined in the `color.xml` file inside my `attrs.xml` file.

for example in color.xml I use `<color name="mypreferencesummary">#e27229</color>`

and in attrs.xml I use `<attr name="mypreferencesummary" format="reference|color" />`

when I call it I get the `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it actually occurred from those xmls?
That error seems to be a missing constructor error when you create custom view and use it in xml layout.